# Can't make shared folder for Win7 Guest

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, xubuntu, windows-7, shared-folders

Can't make a shared folder.

I try many solutions, but еру solutions did not help me.

[image: Shared folders]

But when i type command:

```
net use t: \\vboxsvr\msf
```

> cmd returned: Error 53.

[This guide](https://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Fix-Windows-7-Sharing-in-VirtualBox-123021.shtml) doesn't help me
Host: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Guest: Windows 7 Maximal

Comment: Please provide information: do you mean the folder doesn't get created? Or the folder is not visible from the Win7 side?  Are you using Win7 inside VirtualBox or as a separate dual-boot installation?

Comment: Folder doesn't visible. And i use Win7 inside VirtualBox